# Geoda OECD map question

Tags: mapping, geoda

For my undergraduate thesis I must do a spatial analysis over the OECD countries, but I cannot find a map for them, due to them being so spread apart. Funny thing, even my spatial analysis teacher couldn't do it, so I am wondering if there is any way you know about doing it?

Comment: this data https://stats.oecd.org/OECDregionalstatistics/#story=0 ?

Comment: I need a geoda file so I load the OECD countries.

Comment: Welcome to Geographic Information Systems! If it’s open data that you seek then I think the place to ask is the [Open Data Stack Exchange](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/).